# Displaying track's information (e.g. genre) from inputted SoundCloud URL

Tags: javascript, html, api, attributes, soundcloud

I have managed to get a user's SoundCloud URL input to load into an iFrame in HTML and JavaScript and I now want to display the genre of the loaded track to the user but am unsure of how to do this. I plan to take the genre to create a recommendation system.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="url" value="URL..."><br>

<a id="loadButton" onclick="loadSong();" class="button">LOAD TRACK</a>

<iframe id = "sc-widget" width="80%" height="80%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=single_active=false" ></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadSong(){
  (function() {

    var iframe2 = document.querySelector('#sc-widget');
    var widget = SC.Widget(iframe2);
    var input = document.getElementById("url");

    widget.load(input.value);  

  }());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this properly with the SoundCloud API.  Start here https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide

Comment: Are you recommending to also replace the URL loading method that I have used in my example?